# How to mark only one vertex from every triangle in a Delaunay triangulation

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, geometry, triangulation

Given an array of triangulate points `int[][]` so that every three points represents a triangle, how can I mark (identify) just one point for each triangle so that no individual triangle has more than one point marked.

I'm trying to add a z-value to each point so that every triangle only has one point elevated and the other points both have a z-value of 0. The reason I don't want any flat triangles is because then my light source will have little to no affect on the triangle because the normal angle is always facing the light.

Here's a video. The mouse cursor represents the light source above (ignore the beginning where the mouse doesn't affect the lighting). You'll notice some of the triangles have a constant color to them since all its point have a z-value of 0.

https://streamable.com/w5spi

I've tried just adding a point to the centroid of the triangle and creating three new triangles, but it messes with the uniformity of the triangle spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Delaunay doesn't provide any simple mean to generate depth, I would suggest using a combination of a [Simplex noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_noise) function and the Delaunay triangle points.

This way you can "map" the two on top of each other, extract a value underneath the normalized Delaunay triangle points from the Simplex noise function and use that for Z/elevation.

[image: Illustration]
<sup>Principle: normalize triangle points from Delaunay, extract Z via the SN function using the normalized x/y position.</sup>

There are many Simplex Noise [implementations](https://gist.github.com/banksean/304522#file-perlin-noise-simplex-js) out there for JavaScript. It's worth noting that the *3D version* has a [patent attached](https://www.google.com/patents/US6867776) if using the techniques described within the patent. See [OpenSimplex noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSimplex_noise) for an alternative if 3D is needed - [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-simplex-noise) - in this case though, the 2D version will probably be enough.

Comment: Thanks, using simplex noise seems to generate more natural z-values than just assigning random integers to the points. I ended up using [open-simplex-noise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-simplex-noise).